# Mysql how to count column values and create corresponding column names

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Mysql Version `mysql  Ver 8.0.29-0`

#### Inital table

**tableA**

| name | uid | count | other_columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | a | 1 |  |
| first | b | 2 |  |
| first | c | 1 |  |
| first | d | 2 |  |
| second | e | 1 |  |
| second | f | 2 |  |
| second | g | 1 |  |
| second | h | 1 |  |

**tableB**

| uid | type | other_columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 |  |
| b | 1 |  |
| c | 2 |  |
| d | 2 |  |
| e | 2 |  |
| f | 3 |  |
| g | 3 |  |
| h | 3 |  |

#### try

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, b.type, SUM(a.count)
FROM (
    SELECT `name`, `uid`, `count`
    FROM tableA
) a
INNER JOIN tableB b
ON a.uid = b.uid
GROUP BY a.name, b.type
```

get

| name | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | 1 | 3 |
| first | 2 | 3 |
| second | 2 | 1 |
| second | 3 | 4 |

#### expect

| address | count1 | ratio1 | count2 | ratio2 | count3 | ratio3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | 3 | 0.5 | 3 | 0.5 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| first | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.2 | 4 | 0.8 | 5 |

how can I make it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far and where you got stuck/error/issue you are having?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For your information, the task you want to do is called a [tag:pivot]. It's a notorious pain in the xxx in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have update discription of the problem, and `Saar Levy` gived me an answer. 
You can make other suggestions as your wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a column for each type, by having a condition that gives other types the value of 0 and your desired type the actual value

```
select 
name, 
sum(if(type = 1, count, 0)) count1,
sum(if(type = 2, count, 0)) count2,
sum(if(type = 3, count, 0)) count3,
sum(count) total
from t
group by name;
```

For the ratios, you have 2 options,

1. you can surround the query with another query to
   calculate the ratios:

```
select 
name, 
count1, count1/total as ratio1,
count2, count2/total as ratio2,
count3, count3/total as ratio3,
total
from (select 
name, 
sum(if(type = 1, count, 0)) count1,
sum(if(type = 2, count, 0)) count2,
sum(if(type = 3, count, 0)) count3,
sum(count) total
from t
group by name) t;
```

2. Calculate the ratios directly in the first query:

```
select 
name, 
sum(if(type = 1, count, 0)) count1,
sum(if(type = 1, count, 0)) / sum(count) ratio1,
sum(if(type = 2, count, 0)) count2,
sum(if(type = 2, count, 0)) / sum(count) ratio2,
sum(if(type = 3, count, 0)) count3,
sum(if(type = 3, count, 0)) / sum(count) ratio3,
sum(count) total
from t
group by name;
```

Please note, that I didn't take into consideration the case that your count field has only 0 values, which will lead to a total of 0 and dividing by 0
I don't know if it's possible in your case or not, but if it does, please add another condition checking the total value before calculating the ratios

DB Fiddle that shows the above:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a98530b3d75c0d2938198ad89397c24